# SQL - Why is my query returning all possible permutations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have a table containing the following data

```
ID     Bid    Outcome 
1       2       1
2       2       2
```

I want to query the table with left joins in order to convert the `bid` and `outcome` IDs into a readable view. When I apply  the joins, instead of just converting the FK values, SQL returns all possible permutations of the data.

It could be an error with my `join`

Here is the code, the output and the expected result:

```
SELECT
t1.ID,
b.Name as Bid,
o.Name as Outcome

From table1 as t1 
left join bid as b on b.ID = b.ID 
left join outcome as o on o.ID = o.ID
```

Current result:

```
1       Back    Win
1       Back    Loss
1       Lay     Win
1       Lay     Loss
2       Back    Win
2       Back    Loss
2       Lay     Win
2       Lay     Loss
```

Expected result:

```
ID   Bid   Outcome 
1    Lay   Win
2    Lay   Loss
```

Comment: `anymede as g left join 
bid as b 
on b.ID = b.ID` You Left join on the same column. Same goes for the other `join`

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, *chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Squirrel said, you are joining on the same table, it should be

```
 SELECT
    t1.ID,
    b.Name as Bid,
    o.Name as Outcome
    
    From table1 as t1 
    left join bid as b on b.ID = g.ID 
    left join outcome as o on o.ID = g.ID
```

Comment: It is very unlikely that `ID` of table `gaymede` is the column referencing to the other tables.

Comment: `ganymede` is the main table. `bid` & `outcome` are conversion tables - this is working for me @Squirrel but is this not the correct way?

Comment: @Dallas you didn't show us the schema for all 3 tables, i have no idea what are the column name and can't really comment the query is correct or not. But joining on `b.ID = g.ID` and also `o.ID = g.ID` is rather unusual. I would think it should be something like `b.ID = g.Bid` and `o.ID = g.Outcome`

Comment: This did resolve my problem, I had joined tables on the same column. Although this solution worked, I would reference @Squirrel comment since it supports meaningful naming conventions